# Binding a table to multi-valued parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a project that has some fairly extensive code to calculate values, which I would like to display in an SSRS report.  So instead of recreating that logic in SQL, I would like to pass all the data over as multi-value parameters and list them in a table.  I would pass it a set of multi-value parameters, each of which would populate a column in the table.

Is it possible to bind a table to multi-value parameters, showing a row for each value in a parameter?  If so, how would I do this?

Comment: You can pass over in the URL - you don't say how the report is being launched. How long would the parameter be...?

Comment: Yes it would be launched by calling a URL, but it's not clear to me how that's relevant to the question I'm asking.  There would not be a large amount of data I would be passing to the report.